# Vertical Scroll appears at bottom of the table. Need it to be at top

Tags: java, jsp, scrollbar

I have a jsp page. It contains some table which it extracts from database.
I used < tbody id="x" style="overflow:auto" />
By this the scroll bar appears at bottom. I want it to be at top after I click on button that pops up this page with table.
How should i do it?

Comment: Do you mean the browser scroll bar? I'm not sure if I understand your question rigth.

Comment: yeah the vertical scroll bar appears at bottom of the page. i want it to display the top entries of table on pop up rather than bottom entries. Not the browser scroll bar. actually i have a table inside a table in popup. the one inside has scrollbar which shows the botom entries.

Comment: the table inside is loaded as a
< tr > <  tbody ...as mentioned abve /> < /tr>

Comment: Could you please show a screenshot of your current result and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

There is two way for adding the vertical scroll

first when the height is overflow mean you have to mention the height of the table then it takes affect

otherwise  it Automatically when it found the data form the database and as per the height of the table or page it takes affect.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $(".wrapper1").scroll(function(){
    $(".wrapper2").scrollLeft($(".wrapper1").scrollLeft());
  });
  $(".wrapper2").scroll(function(){
    $(".wrapper1").scrollLeft($(".wrapper2").scrollLeft());
  });

});
$(document).ready(function(){
var a=$(".div2 > table").width()+50;
$('.div2').css('width',a+'px');
$('.div1').css('width',a+'px');

});

        </script>



 <style>
.wrapper1, .wrapper2 {width:100%;overflow-x: scroll;overflow-y:hidden;}
.wrapper1 {height: 20px; }
.div1 {width:2500px;height: 20px;}
.div2 {width:2500px;overflow: auto;}
        </style>
<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="div1"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="div2"><table></table></div>
</div>
```